# Finding the concavity of a function without having to plot

Tags: calculus

I am given a function $f(x)$.

I determined that $f(x)'' = 0$ precisely when $x$ is $4$ or $-3$.

I am asked to find the interval for which the function is concave down.

How can I do it by knowing the values $x = 4$ and $x = -3$ and without having to plot the function?

Comment: I edited your question to try to fill in some gaps. Please verify that I interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity let us assume that the second derivative is everywhere defined and continuous. You have found that $f''(x)=0$ at $x=4$ and at $x=-3$. That is not enough to determine concavity, it only locates the points where concavity **might** change.

In most simple cases, concavity will change at these points, but it need not. To determine concavity, you need to examine the **signs** of $f''(x)$ is the intervals $(-\infty,-3)$, $(-3,4)$, and $(4,\infty)$. (Under our conditions, the sign of $f''(x)$ can only change at $-3$ and $4$.)

If for example $f''(x)=(x+3)(x-4)$, then $f''(x)$ is positive in $(-\infty,-3)$, negative in $(-3,4)$, and positive in $(4,\infty)$, so we get concave up, then down, then up.

However, if $f''(x)=(x+3)^2(x-4)$, the story changes: we get down, down, up. And in the case $f''(x)=(x+3)^2(x-4)^2$, we get up, up, up.

Comment: I just realized continuity shouldn't be required, by MVT. I think. Maybe that's wrong.

Comment: So after I calculate the points, I use the f(x)'' to determine the concavity and not the original f(x)?

Comment: Yes, for concavity you are working with $f''(x)$ only. In my exposition, I simplified things by assuming continuity. Concavity might also change where $f''(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: André, I'm thinking that you can dispense with continuity by using MVT and replacing a second derivative sign test with a "brute-force" three-point convexity/concavity test for each interval, evaluating $f$ at five points. Is this right?

Comment: I have not thought about it enough, you are probably right, the second derivative, if it exists, will have the intermediate value property. The answer was in a first-year calculus context. Out of guilt I did mention in a comment that one has to also look where the second derivative does not exist. That *can* happen in a standard problem.

Answer (score 0):

If $f''$ is *continuous*, then you only need to know it at three more points: one less than $-3$, one between $-3$ and $4$, and one greater than $4$. Do you see why you need these? If $f''$ is not continuous, then you may need to know much more.